# Is it possible to use a custom hook inside useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very basic custom hook that takes in a path an returns a document from firebase

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../sharedComponents/Firebase';

function useGetDocument(path) {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)
    const [document, setDocument] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const getDocument = async () => {
            let snapshot = await firebase.db.doc(path).get()
            let document = snapshot.data()
            document.id = snapshot.id
            setDocument(document)
        }
        getDocument()
    }, []);

    return document
}

export default useGetDocument
```

Then I use useEffect as a componentDidMount/constructor to update the state

```
useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {

      let docSnapshot = await useGetDocument("products/" + products[selectedProduct].id + "labels/list")
      if(docSnapshot) {
        let tempArray = []
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(docSnapshot.list)) {
          tempArray.push({id: key, color: value.color, description: value.description})
        }
        setLabels(tempArray)
      } else {
        setLabels([])
      }

      await props.finishLoading()
      await setLoading(false)
    }
    init()
  }, [])
```

However, I get an Invariant Violation from "throwInvalidHookError" which means that I am breaking the rules of hooks, so my question is whether you can't use custom hooks inside useEffect, or if I am doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 40):

As far as I know, the hooks in a component should always be in the same order. And since the `useEffect` happens sometimes and not every render that does break the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). It looks to me like your `useGetDocument` has no real need.

I propose the following solution:

1. Keep your `useGetDocument` the same.
2. Change your component to have a `useEffect` that has the `document` as a dependency.

Your component could look like the following:

```
const Component = (props) => {
    // Your document will either be null (according to your custom hook) or the document once it has fetched the data.
    const document = useGetDocument("products/" + products[selectedProduct].id + "labels/list");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (document && document !== null) {
            // Do your initialization things now that you have the document.
        }
    }, [ document ]);

   return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can't use a hook inside another hook because it breaks the rule `Call Hooks from React function components` and the function you pass to `useEffect` is a regular javascript function.

What you can do is call a hook inside another custom hook.

What you need to do is call `useGetDocument` inside the component and pass the result in the `useEffect` dependency array.

```
let docSnapshot = await useGetDocument("products/" + products[selectedProduct].id + "labels/list")

useEffect(() => { ... }, [docSnapshot])
```

This way, when `docSnapshot` changes, your `useEffect` is called.

Comment: I see, but let's assume that I want to get an updated version of the document, by calling the useGetDocument again. Would this be impossible to do with hooks?

Comment: @Andreas if you want to `get an updated version of the document, by calling`, you shouldn't create a custom hook, but just a normal function that gets the document. If you want to use hooks, you should implement a event listener when the document changes in your `useGetDocument` it updates the state, so when the document changes, it updates `docSnapshot` and calls your `useEffect` again.

Comment: Sorry if I can't give the complete code because I don't know enough of firebase, but I know what logic you need and can lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 21):

Of course you can call hooks in other hooks.

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

But...

**You are not using a hook inside another hook**.

You realise that you what you pass to useEffect is a **callback**, hence you are using your custom hook inside the body of the callback and not the hook (useEffect).

If you happen to use ESLint and the react-hooks plugin, it'll warn you:

`ESLint: React Hook "useAttachDocumentToProspectMutation" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)`

That being said, you don't need a useEffect at all. And useGetDocument doesn't return a promise but a document.

When calling your hook

```
const document = useGetDocument("products/" + products[selectedProduct].id + "labels/list");
```

It will return undefined the first time around, then the document for the subsequent renders as per @ApplePearPerson's answer.