# React custom hook causes infinite loops

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, swr

any idea why this custom hook with SWR causes an infinite loop?

```
export const useOrganization = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<OrganizationModel | undefined>();
  const { organizationId } = useParams();
  const { data: dataSWR } = useSWRImmutable<
    AxiosResponse<Omit<OrganizationModel, 'id'>>
  >(`organizations/${organizationId}`, api);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataSWR?.data && organizationId) {
      setData({ id: organizationId, ...dataSWR.data });
      console.log({ id: organizationId, ...dataSWR.data });
    }
  });
  return data;
};
```

I need to fetch data from API and add missing id from URL param. If I use setData(dataSWR.data), everything is fine. The problem occurs when setData({...dataSWR.data}) is used -> loop.

Comment: You need to unsderstand how `useEffect` used in different scenario. Try this way . useEffect(() => {
    if (dataSWR?.data && organizationId) {
      setData({ id: organizationId, ...dataSWR.data });
      console.log({ ...dataSWR.data });
    }
  }, [organizationId])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - useMemo hook:

```
export const useOrganization = () => {
  const { organizationId } = useParams();
  const { data } = useSWRImmutable<
    AxiosResponse<Omit<OrganizationModel, 'id'>>
  >(`organizations/${organizationId}`, api);

  const result = useMemo(() => {
    if (data && organizationId) {
      return { id: organizationId, ...data.data };
    }
  }, [data, organizationId]);
  console.log('useOrganization');
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Without useMemo, a new object is created (by spread syntax) whenever the hook is called. It doesn't loop if just "data" from SWR are returned, because it return always the same object.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `useEffect` based on the scenario. When `dataSWR` changed the `useEffect` call again with new data.

You can add the `dataSWR` as dependencies argument in `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => { do something... }, [dataSWR])
```

**Example:**

```
export const useOrganization = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<OrganizationModel | undefined>();
  const { organizationId } = useParams();
  const { data: dataSWR } = useSWRImmutable<AxiosResponse<Omit<OrganizationModel, 'id'>>>(`organizations/${organizationId}`, API);

  useEffect(() => {
   if (dataSWR?.data && organizationId) {
      setData({ id: organizationId, ...dataSWR.data });
      console.log({ id: organizationId, ...dataSWR.data });
    };
  },[dataSWR]);

  return data;
};
```

Usage of hook:

```
const data = useOrganization()
```

Dependencies argument of `useEffect` is `useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

Let's explore side effects and runs:

**Not provided: the side-effect runs after every rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs after EVERY rendering
  });  
}
```

**An empty array []: the side-effect runs once after the initial rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
  }, []);
}
```

**Has props or state values `[prop1, prop2, ..., state1, state2]`: the side-effect runs only when any dependency value changes.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
}
```

Comment: but is `useSWRImmutable` itself a hook(based on name, it is)? if it is, we will have violation of rules of hooks(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070930/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-hook-inside-useeffect-in-react has better explanation than official docs, unfortunately).

Comment: So, you can add dependency in `useEffect()`. 
Example : `useEffect(() => { do something... }, [dataSWR ])`

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought it's better to put in answer, that is excellent in every other way

Comment: Update the answer. It's good now?

Comment: Yep! Thank you!